# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (macOS, postgresql 15.1, pgAdmin 4)

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

After installing PSQL 15.1 (https://www.postgresql.org/download/), I try to connect to the server, enter the password that I set during installation. But I am getting this error `[connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"]`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPt7g.png)

Any idea how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What message is in the database server's log file?

Comment: in pgadmin4.log file right?
2022-12-23 13:42:16,873: WARNING  werkzeug:  WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2022-12-23 14:36:33,597: ERROR  pgadmin:  Could not connect to server(#1) - 'PostgreSQL 15'.
Error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: No, the database server log.  pgAdmin4 is the application server, not the database server.  The database server knows why the password authentication failed, but it won't provide you or pgAdmin4 with the full details, as you are not authenticated and the details might help an attacker.

Comment: @jjanes I found what you are talking about: 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
DETAIL:Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 89: "host  all  all  ::1/128  scram-sha-256"

Comment: Scram is less explicit than md5 is here, but if that is the entire message, it means the password is wrong (as opposed the password being missing or corrupt or expired, or the user or database not existing).  Maybe you can log in over the local socket without a password, and reset it.  Or temporarily change the auth method to trust, long enough to reset the password.

Comment: @jjanes I wanted to thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I found what was the problem. When you enter a password, you cannot view it, unfortunately. And the next setting is the port, and I was very surprised that when I entered the letters there, they turned out to be in the language of the system that I have installed (Ukrainian), although my keyboard language was set to English. That's why I had this error. To avoid this, I simply entered the password separately and copied it into the password fields. And now everything works!)

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem.
During installation, the entered password cannot be viewed unfortunately. And the next setting is the port, and I was very surprised that when I entered letters there, they turned out to be in the system language (I have Ukrainian installed), although my keyboard language was set to English. That's why I had this error.
**To avoid this, I simply entered the password separately and copied it into the password field.**
And now everything works, I hope this helps someone!